# How to sort a list of different types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I need to sort a list using python 3. There might be `strings`, `integers`, `floats`, or `tuples`, etc.

I am currently trying to make correct use of the `sort` function using the `key` parameter like this:

```
data.sort(key=gen_key)

...

def gen_key(self, value):
        if is_number(value):
            return str(value)

        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
    return '___' + type(value).__name__
```

But the problem is that numbers will now be sorted naturally. While I want to order the numbers and floats still like numbers and floats instead of treating them as strings.

The behavior is caused by the `return str(value)` part. But i cannot return a different type than a string, as that will raise an exception, as of python 3 strings wont be sorted with numbers like they did in python 2. The exception is the following

```
unordarable types: int() < str()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What result are you expecting? How do you expect to sort strings and tuples?

Comment: And how would you *want* `'A'` to sort vs `13`? You'll need to come up with a well-defined sort order. Once you've done that, you'll pretty much be done already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to use as the sorting key an object that contains the desired sorting behavior in its comparison methods. The only comparison method needed by Python sorting is `__lt__()`, so this is reasonably straightforward.

For example, here is a class that implements, roughly, the Python 2 sorting heuristic (sort in value within groups of objects that are comparable). You could of course implement any other rule you like. Since sorting will create one of these objects for every item in your list I kept the size of each object as low as possible by using `__slots__` and by interning all the type strings.

```
from sys import intern

class Py2Key:

    __slots__ = ("value", "typestr")

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value   = value
        self.typestr = intern(type(value).__name__)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value < other.value
        except TypeError:
            return self.typestr < other.typestr
```

Usage:

```
seq = ["Z", 3, "Y", 1, "X", 2.5, False]
sorted(seq, key=Py2Key)
>>> [False, 1, 2.5, 3, 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Unfortunately, implementing Python 2's sorting behavior in Python 3 is going to be slower and more memory-intensive than Python 2 was, especially since we're taking advantage of exception handling. Whether this is acceptable in your application is up to you.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to make your `key` function return a tuple with a guaranteed comparable type in the first index, and the disparate types in subsequent indices.

While not 100% identical to what Python 2 does, for your specific case of "numbers to the front, everything else compared by typename" you can do this with a reasonably efficient `key` function:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> seq = ['Z', 3, 'Y', 1, 'X', 2.5, False, (1, 2), [2, 3], None]
>>> sorted(seq, key=lambda x: (x is not None, '' if isinstance(x, Number) else type(x).__name__, x))
[None, False, 1, 2.5, 3, [2, 3], 'X', 'Y', 'Z', (1, 2)]
```

The `key` function here makes the first element of the `key` a simple `bool`, forcing `None` to sort before everything else (Py2 did the same thing), then sorting all numeric types first by using the empty string for the second part of the key, where everything else uses their type name (also like Py2). Once you've gotten past those first two indices, what's left is the same type, and should compare just fine.

The main flaw here is that comparable non-numeric types like `set` and `frozenset` won't compare to one another, they'll be sorted by typename only (a custom key class using exceptions could handle this).

It also won't handle the recursive case; if the sequence contains `[2, 3]` and `['a', 'b']`, it will have a `TypeError` comparing `2` with `'a'`, but nothing short of a ridiculously involved key class could handle that.

If that's not an issue, this is cheap to run and relatively simple.

Unlike solutions involving custom classes with `__lt__` defined to perform the comparison, this approach has the advantage of generating built-in keys, which compare efficiently with minimal execution of Python-level code during the sort.

Timings:

```
 # Multiply out the sequence so log n factor in n log n work counts for something
 >>> seq = ['Z', 3, 'Y', 1, 'X', 2.5, False, (1, 2), [2, 3], None] * 100

 # Verify equivalence
 >>> sorted(seq, key=Py2Key) == sorted(seq, key=lambda x: (x is not None, '' if isinstance(x, Number) else type(x).__name__, x))
 True

 # Timings in seconds for the fastest time (of 3 trials) to run the sort 1000 times:
 >>> import timeit

 # Py2Key class
 >>> min(timeit.repeat('sorted(seq, key=Py2Key)', 'from __main__ import seq, Py2Key', number=1000))
 5.251885865057375

 >>> min(timeit.repeat('sorted(seq, key=lambda x: (x is not None, "" if isinstance(x, Number) else type(x).__name__, x))', 'from __main__ import seq, Number', number=1000))
 1.9556877178131344
```

Basically, avoiding the overhead of dynamic Python-level `__lt__` is reducing runtime by just over 60%. It doesn't seem to be an algorithmic improvement (a `seq` 100 times longer has the same runtime ratio), just a reduction in fixed overhead, but it's a non-trivial reduction.

Comment: Can you extend the approach with user-defined keys. For example, the iterable may consist of dictionary where user wants to sort on a specific dict key `key=lambda x: x['mykey']`, and as above the values associated to `x[mykey]` may be of mixed type. I wonder if your lambda can be post-composed. Will try.

Comment: Seems ok:   `seqd = [{'a':x} for x in seq]`. then `sorted(seqd,key = lambda x: type_markup(x['a']))` where `type_markup` is your lambda.