# What are built-in Python 3 types that can be compared to each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison, operators, typing

In Python 2, it was possible to compare objects of different types such as `int` to `str` by having an implicit comparison of the text string of types (that is, in lexicographic order, string `'int'` is less than string `'str'` and string `'list'` is less than string `'tuple'`).

Hence, in Python 2, `5 < 'hello'` returns `True`. One can read more about why this was allowed in answer to [Why is ''>0 True in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384139).

In Python 3, this raises `builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()` exception.

This [web page](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html) says

> The strict approach to comparing in Python 3 makes it **generally**
>   impossible to compare different types of objects.

Does it mean there are some built-in types or special cases where it would be possible for any built-in types to be compared without causing `TypeError`? I am not talking about custom types where the necessary dunder methods are implemented to properly support comparison.

Comment: Sure, you can compare `int` to `float` for a start. You can also compare them with `bool`. You can also compare `set` to `frozenset`.

Comment: There's more to the Python 2 behavior than just string-comparing the type names. For example, `5 < ArithmeticError()` even though `'int' > 'ArithmeticError'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these are valid statements (and they all evaluate to `True`):

```py
0 < True
0 < 1.
0. < True
{0} < frozenset((0, 1))
```

The only thing that may look odd here is that `0. == False` and `1. == True`.

On the other hand, you can still reproduce what python 2 does by casting your value to an `str` before comparing it (this also evaluate to `True`):

```py
str(5) < 'hello'
```

If you really need this behaviour you can always have a function that will cast/compare. That way you'll guarantee that objects of different types will always compare the same way, which seems to be the only constraint in python 2.

```py
def lt(a, b):
    return str(a) < str(b)
```

Or maybe even better, you can cast only when needed:

```py
def lt(a, b):
  try: 
    return a < b
  except TypeError: 
    return str(a) < str(b)
```

On the other hand, as suggested in the comments, in CPython's implementation, it seems like comparison is done in the following way:

```py
def lt(a, b):
  try: 
    return a < b
  except TypeError: 
    if a is None:
      return True
    if b is None: 
      return False
    if isinstance(a, numbers.Number):
      return True
    if isinstance(b, numbers.Number):
      return False
    return str(type(a)) < str(type(b))
```

Comment: OK, this is useful. Comparison of `int` and `bool` discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so it's not really odd that you can compare `bool`s to other numbers.

Comment: Maybe that's because I'm used to 0/1 acting as bool, maybe comparing `int` to `bool` is also odd and I just got over it.

Comment: The Python 2 behavior is not equivalent to `str(5) < 'hello'`. The Python 2 behavior is a bizarre, implementation-dependent pile of quirks, but for the specific case of `5 < 'hello'` on CPython, `5` is considered smaller because it's a number and `'hello'` isn't.

Comment: You may have misinterpreted the part where the question asserts that the values are compared by *type* name, not by stringifying the values. Type name comparison is a part of the weird pile of quirks, though not the whole story.

Comment: Aren't number always "smaller" than strings with this solution? Or maybe you mean that other types will not be sorted similarly as in python 2?

Comment: With your code, `5` compares greater than `'4'`, contrary to how `5 < '4'` in actual CPython 2.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to update my answer with something that look a bit more like what python 2 does then.

Comment: It looks like what I implemented is also valid as the only constraint in python 2 seems to be consistency.

Comment: One more problem with None, None.

py3: lt(None, None) =>True;
py2: lt(None, None) => False;
py2: (None < None) => None.

Answer (score 1):

I had already looked this up on the web before, and it appears they are indeed unsortable in Python 3, apart from the few special cases mentionned above.

> The change usually manifests itself in sorting lists: in Python 3, lists with items of different types are generally not sortable.
>   If you need to sort heterogeneous lists, or compare different types of objects, implement a key function to fully describe how disparate types should be ordered.
>   *[Source](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html)*

I don't know why, but some found ways to reproduce the behavior of Python 2 using Python 3.

Maybe you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756863/python-sort-different-types-in-list) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575183/how-can-i-get-2-x-like-sorting-behaviour-in-python-3-x). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167657/python-list-greater-than-number) also highlighted the change in 2011:

> Found it: Buried in PEP 3100: "Comparisons other than == and != between disparate types will raise an exception unless explicitly supported by the type"